# sending a list group to the database (mysql)

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a list-group that i want to insert into my database. I'm able to connect alright to the database, but no data is sent. The ID keeps increasing, but the other fields are blank. I need help on how to send the list items to the database. Below are my codes.

```
 <div class="list-group" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method='post'
 action="thankyou.php">
             <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">Specifications</a>
               <a href="#" class="list-group-item" type="text" name="car_type"><b>Car Type :</b> 2012 Honda Civic</a>
               <a href="#" class="list-group-item" type="text" name="trim"><b>Trim :</b> STANDARD</a>
               <a href="#" class="list-group-item" type="text" name="year_made"><b>Year :</b> 2012</a>
               <a href="#" class="list-group-item" type="text" name="km"><b>KM :</b> 19,000</a>
               <a href="#" class="list-group-item" type="text" name="exterior_color"><b>Exterior Colour :</b> WHITE</a>
               <a href="#" class="list-group-item" type="text" name="cost_after_duty"><b>Cost After Duty :</b> $21,960</a>
               <a href="#" class="list-group-item" type="text" name="options"><b>OPTIONSB(A/T) :</b> ALLOYS, BLUETOOTH, BODY KIT,
 POWER GROUP, KEYLESS REMOTE, BACK UP CAMERA</a>
               <a href="#" class="list-group-item" name="percentage_deposite"><b>30% Deposit :</b> </a>  
               <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="thankyou.php" type="submit">Make Reservation &raquo;</a>
           </div>
```

Below are the php codes for the insertion.

```
> <?php ob_start(); session_start();
> 
> $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","233apps","233apps","car_sales"); //
> Check connection if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {   echo "Failed to
> connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); }
> 
> $car_uploads = "vehicles";
> 
> // escape variables for security
> 
> $car_type = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['car_type']);
> //$company = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['company']);
> $year_made = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['year_made']);
> $trim = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['trim']); $km =
> mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['km']); $exterior_color =
> mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['exterior_color']); $options =
> mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['options']); $cost_after_duty =
> mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['cost_after_duty']);
> $percentage_deposite = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,
> $_POST['$percentage_deposite']); $reserver =
> mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['reserver']);
> 
> 
> 
> $sql = " INSERT INTO vehicles( car_type, year_made, trim, km,
> exterior_color, options,cost_after_duty, percentage_deposite, reserver
> ) VALUES ( '$car_type','$year_made', '$trim', '$km',
> '$exterior_color', '$options', '$cost_after_duty',
> '$percentage_deposite', '$reserver' )";
> 
> if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {   die('Error: ' .
> mysqli_error($con)); } echo "";
> 
> mysqli_close($con); ?>
```

Comment: What code are you using for inserting into database?

Comment: You seem to be using a `<div>` element instead of a `<form>` element

Comment: You have a `href` to the same URL as your `action`.. thats not right

Comment: please post the complete code

Comment: You need to post the code with which you insert aswell. Beside that this mostly looks like you should check out an manual for forms in html first.

Comment: I'm using mysql @Genhis

Comment: Its a list, so i don't want to use a form and also i have removed the href as you suggested but it's still not working @ChrisMaggs

Comment: i have posted the codes for the insertions as well. @AbdoAdel

Comment: i have posted the codes for the insertions as well. @DocRattie

Answer (score 1):

**Form**

This might sound rough, but you should read some guides on html forms, as you messed up quite a lot.

```
<div class="list-group" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method='post' action="thankyou.php">
```

You're using a `<div>`instead of a `<form>`. Thus all of this can't work at all. It should look like this:

```
<form class="list-group" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method='post' action="thankyou.php">
```

**Input**

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item active">Specifications</a>
<a href="#" class="list-group-item" type="text" name="car_type"><b>Car Type :</b> 2012 Honda Civic</a>
<a href="#" class="list-group-item" type="text" name="trim"><b>Trim :</b> STANDARD</a>
<a href="#" class="list-group-item" type="text" name="year_made"><b>Year :</b> 2012</a>
<a href="#" class="list-group-item" type="text" name="km"><b>KM :</b> 19,000</a>
<a href="#" class="list-group-item" type="text" name="exterior_color"><b>Exterior Colour :</b> WHITE</a>
<a href="#" class="list-group-item" type="text" name="cost_after_duty"><b>Cost After Duty :</b> $21,960</a>
<a href="#" class="list-group-item" type="text" name="options"><b>OPTIONSB(A/T) :</b> ALLOYS, BLUETOOTH, BODY KIT, POWER GROUP, KEYLESS REMOTE, BACK UP CAMERA</a>
<a href="#" class="list-group-item" name="percentage_deposite"><b>30% Deposit :</b> </a>  
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="thankyou.php" type="submit">Make Reservation &raquo;</a>
```

I asume that this Block is supposed to be the Inputs in your Form. But you only use links. That can't work at all. And it's the reason you only insert empty data. No links are avaliable in `$_POST`. To get all of that working you need real inputs:

You can use the `value` tag to get some default-value in there. But than a user can put somethin into the input. And with a submit-Button the form can be send to your page to deal with it. Something like this:

```
 <input type="submit" value="send">
```

After you fixed all of that you can check again if the result in the DB is allright.